# Firefox stalls at Ajax call to Asmx

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

Recently Firefox stopped sending Ajax calls to a WebService WebMethod we have in an .asmx.cs page. Basically, FF won't even attempt to make this call. I have seen other posts with similar problems but so far I haven't found any solutions. This has never been a problem before (as if a new FF update is the culprit) and the following seems to work just fine in Chrome and IE. This is the Javascript:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    var hash = 'JzVpYbr48';
    var dataS = JSON.stringify({ sessionHash: hash, customerID: '010000' });

    $('#foo').on('click', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "http://localhost/MVRC/ad.asmx/GetAchievementsSummary",
            contentType: 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: dataS,
            success: function (res) {
                console.log("badges success");
            },
            error: function (res) {
                console.log("badges failure");
            }
        });

    });
});
</script>
```

This is basically the code behind:

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://www.ourdomain.com/mvrc")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.None)]
[System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class ad : System.Web.Services.WebService
{

    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public object GetAchievementsSummary(string sessionHash, string customerID)
    {
        return new { foo = "blah", bar = "blah" };
    }
}
```

And for what it's worth, here are a few possibly pertinent snippets from the web.config:

```
<location path="ad.asmx">
  <system.web>
    <webServices>
      <protocols>
        <add name="HttpGet" />
        <add name="HttpPost" />
      </protocols>
      <conformanceWarnings>
        <remove name="BasicProfile1_1" />
      </conformanceWarnings>
    </webServices>
  </system.web>
</location>
<system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
        <customHeaders>
            <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
          <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
        </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>
```

Browser console doesn't seem to show any errors.

Comment: Have you debugged it inside Firefox's console? Does it actually get to the "$.ajax(" call?

Comment: Code in the post does not demonstrate the problem (assuming page rendered from `http://localhost`, no ports/same schema). Make sure information in the post allows one to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Juan, yes I have debugged inside Firefox's console and it gets to the ajax. Like I said everything works fine in other browsers as well.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is embarrassing but here is what I've found. The add blocker addon 'Add Block Plus' for Firefox was blocking this ajax call. However, it should be noted that I actually set up a separate Web Forms test solution with a Web Service (asmx.cs) in it and tested it as well. And ajax calls through Firefox with ADP worked. So something in my Company's product in combination with Firefox/ADP is a bad combination. Luckily, we don't support ADP so I don't think this will be a problem. Nevertheless, this is what I found.